# Compare headers of two delimited text files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

**File1.txt(base file)**

```
header1|header2|header3|header4

1|2|3|4
```

**File2.txt**

```
header1|header10|header3|header4

5|6|7
```

**Desired O/P**

> header2 is missing in file 2 at position 2
>
> header10 is addition in file 2 at position 2

I need to compare two file header and need to display missing header or addition columns with respect to base file header list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`, like this:

*check.awk*

```
# In the first line of every input file save the headers
FNR==1{
    headers[f++]=$0
}

# Once all lines of input have been processed ...
END{

    # split() returns the number of items. The resulting
    # arrays 'a|b_headers' will be indexed starting from 1
    lena = split(headers[0],a_headers,"|")
    lenb = split(headers[1],b_headers,"|")

    for(h=1;h<=lena;h++) {
        if(a_headers[h] != b_headers[h]) {
            print a_headers[h] " missing from file2 at column " h
        }
    }

    for(h=1;h<=lenb;h++) {
        if(b_headers[h] != a_headers[h]) {
            print b_headers[h] " missing from file1 at column " h
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f check.awk File1.txt File2.txt
```

Output:

```
header2 missing from file2 at column 2
header10 missing from file1 at column 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You are welcome! But wait, there is still a little bug in there when handling files that have not the same number of headers. Just realized that. Will update the post once I've fixed it. Give me a minute ....

Answer (score 3):

I would try it with the `diff` command like this:

```
diff <(head -n1 fh1.txt | tr "|" "\n") <( head -n1 fh2.txt | tr "|" "\n")
```

where fh1.txt and fh2.txt are your files. The output gives the information that you want but it is not so verbose.